# arcpy.AddMessage and codepage problems

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox

Some times in my tools I need to output Cyrillic text via `arcpy.AddMessage` function.

Previously in 10.0 it was very easy. I had .py file of the tool saved in UTF8 codepage.
This code wrote messages in Cyrillic with system locale 'cp1251':

```
source_message = u'Some Cyrillic text here'
message = source_message.encode('cp1251')
arcpy.AddMessage(message)
```

But in 10.1 the same piece of code writes `<msg>0;` to messages.

I have tried several ways of output (utf8, cp1251, unicode) with combinations of saving source .py file in different codepages - no way.

May be anybody faced similar problems in 10.1 ?

PS I am trying to run this tool in ArcCatalog 10.1 sp1

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem because i'm from Serbia and we also use 'cp1251' for our letters. Try to encode with 'utf-8', and then print it, but just add:

```
arcpy.AddMessage(unicode(message))
```

Comment: Have you tried it in 10.1 ? Because this method works for me too in 10.0 but not in 10.1.

Comment: Sorry i didn't try in 10.1.